# Composition of continuous function with holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem.

> Suppose $U,V$ are connected domains in $\mathbf C$. Define functions $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to\mathbf C$ so that $f$ is continuous and $g$ is holomorphic. Show that if $g\circ f$ is constant then at least one of $f$ or $g$ is also constant.

I'm familiar with the conclusions of Liouville's theorem and the Little Picard Theorem but I don't believe they are relevant here because they concern entire functions, whereas $g\circ f$ is defined only on a domain $U\subset\mathbf C$. I'm also not sure how to use the fact that $U$ and $V$ are connected.

The farthest I've gotten is to suppose toward a contradiction that neither $f$ nor $g$ is constant. Then there are points $u_1,u_2\in U$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ with $f(u_1)\neq f(u_2)$ and $g(v_1)\neq g(v_2)$. Beyond this I'm pretty lost. Any help on how to proceed from here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g\circ f=c$. If the range of $f$ has limit point then the identity theorem applied to $g-c$ shows that $g$ is a constant. Otherwise $f(U)$ is a discrete set so it is not connected unless it is  singleton. In the later case $f$ is a constant.